# Web3j Android java solidity wrapper errors

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

Trying to use web3j to invoke some functions in a contract. I followed solidity guide and got the .abi and .bin of this contract - https://etherscan.io/address/0x9dda40dabd849bbb087dcbcf0c5223ec5ffa0ad7#code. Then used web3j commandline to make the .java file wrapper, outputted to the correct directory.

Everything works but these lines:

```
public static final Event FUNDSWITHDRAWN_EVENT = new Event("FundsWithdrawn",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
;

public static final Event FUNDSDEPOSITED_EVENT = new Event("FundsDeposited",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
;

public static final Event SERVERADDED_EVENT = new Event("ServerAdded",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
;

public static final Event SERVERREMOVED_EVENT = new Event("ServerRemoved",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
;

public static final Event GAMESTARTED_EVENT = new Event("GameStarted",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}, new TypeReference<DynamicArray<Address>>() {}));
;

public static final Event GAMEENDED_EVENT = new Event("GameEnded",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}, new TypeReference<Address>() {}, new TypeReference<Address>() {}, new TypeReference<Address>() {}));
;
```

throw error:

```
Event() in Event cannot be applied to:
Expected Parameters:
Actual Arguments:

name:
String
"ServerAdded"  
indexedParameters:
List<TypeReference<?>>
Arrays...new TypeReference<Uint256>() {})  
nonIndexedParameters:
List<TypeReference<?>>
```

And these two lines:

```
    public static final Event OWNERSHIPRENOUNCED_EVENT = new Event("OwnershipRenounced",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}));
;

public static final Event OWNERSHIPTRANSFERRED_EVENT = new Event("OwnershipTransferred",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}));
;
```

Give error:
    TypeReference( ) 
    in TypeReference cannot be applied
    to
    (boolean)

I'm not the contract creator, but it does work correctly in its web3js and metamask implementation. One thing I'm thinking as these events are for serverside, do I even need to include them? (although as you can see they are referenced later) but I'm just wondering if the use of the .bin file forces you to not change things? New to this anyway so any help or direction pointing appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It’s unclear what your question is. If you’re trying to listen to the events, you have to setup an `EthFilter` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083825/interacting-with-the-smart-contract-from-java-application-we3j/49090548#49090548). If you’re asking if you’re required to use events....no.

Comment: This is errors in syntax I believe, not error shown on compilation. red line under text error. The java file says "do not edit" also, so I dunno if I can just remove parts.

Comment: It’s just generated code, so you can do whatever you want with it. It sounds like it’s just an issue with the Java version you have selected for your project in the IDE. If it compiles fine (which it should) but the IDE is showing a syntax error, you’re using different versions.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me, seems a problem with the version because the generation of the Java class has syntax errors.

All you can do is try to fix the issue manually: delete the true, and change a bit the code.

```
public static final Event OWNERSHIPRENOUNCED_EVENT = new Event("OwnershipRenounced",
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}),
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}));
;
```